# Is there any alternative for .unload() in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have click event attached to multiple buttons on my page.And every button loads .php file in same div.

Now the problem is that after few clicks the time to load increases.

```
$('#start').click(function() {
        $('#mainbody').load("content1.php");
    });

    $('#repo').click(function() {

        $('#mainbody').load("content3.php");
    });

    $('#cont').click(function() {
        $('#mainbody').load("content2.php");
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure once a JS block is loaded, it goes into browser memory. Don't think you can unsee in JS without a refresh.

Comment: I don't think [`unload`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) ever did what you thought it did anyway...

Comment: My guess is you are re-binding these click events due to the same script being included on `content1/2/3.php`, meaning each additional time you click on one of these links, it loads the content that many times * the number of times you've clicked previously. Look at your network tab to confirm.

Comment: Yes you are correct @KevinB.What should be done now?

Comment: Using server-side code, detect if the request is ajax. If it's ajax, don't return any javascript

Answer (score 2):

You could just empty the div's HTML using

```
$('#mainbody').html('');
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help

```
$('#mainbody').empty().load("content2.php");
```

Comment: Nothing works.Every time i click , the time to load increases.Its visible on timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Using server-side code, detect if the request is ajax. If it's ajax, don't return any javascript with your content pages. Here's the php way:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // echo javascript includes here

}
```